# BigQuery - Billed for Queries on my account that I did not run

Tags: google-bigquery

When I look through my query history on the new UI i can see queries that I have not run and at times when I have not had access to BigQuery. These tend to be simple queries, on tables that i have interacted with but appear to be generated by some kind of software, given the strange SQL. I have confirmed through the cmd line that these queries were run on my account.

[image: Screenshot of Suspicious Query]

SQL:

```sql
SELECT t0.Branch,
       t0.Customer_Type,
       COUNT(1.000000000000000) AS t0_qt_83wd73hgqb,
       COUNT(1.000000000000000) AS t0_qt_f0hbgeh6pb,
       COUNT(1.000000000000000) AS t0_qt_jlxx8un6pb
FROM `Redacted_Table_Name` AS t0
GROUP BY t0.Branch, t0.Customer_Type
ORDER BY t0_qt_83wd73hgqb DESC;
```

I have noticed these before but most are on cached data, it is only as this one has billed us that i have begun to investigate. Our organisation is new to using BigQuery but I'm guessing this might be something akin to indexing? All developers in my organisation can see these on their accounts sometimes happening dozens of times in a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the data linked to anywhere else such as Data Studio? If so, that runs queries which will be logged and look similar to the above

Comment: additionally you can check if any other APP has access to run queries on your behalf here: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions some google drive extensions use that